# Forms aren't activated on rasa 2.0.2

Tags: forms, rasa

Ok so I'm running Rasa 2.0.2 and whenever I try to activate my forms, rasa seems to fail loading them. I'm pretty sure that my code runs properly since it runs on rasa 2.7.0. Also note that through some threads that I read online I knew that older versions of rasa need the utters with a certain naming such as: "utter_ask_name" so I did that and also slots need to be named like this: "slot_date". So I used both of these methods but still came to no success.
Any help?

domain.yml:

version: "2.0"

```
intents:
- greet
- inform
- subscribe
- bot_challenge
- name
- age
- learn
- book demo
- describe
- describe more
- learn more
- learn less
- date
- time
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- country
- kai101


slots:
  email1:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false
  slot_date:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false
  slot_time:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false
  slot_firstname:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false
  slot_lastname:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false
  slot_email:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false
  slot_country:
    type: unfeaturized
    influence_conversation: false



responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: |
      Hello & welcome to achatbotAgancy.com! Your one-stop shop to the world of chatbots.
      How may I assist you?
    buttons:
    - title: "Learn about chatbots"
      payload: '/learn'
    - title: "What do you want your chatbot to do? In a few words describe the purpose of your chatbot:"
      payload: '/describe'
    - title: "Book a demo to test drive us"
      payload: '/book demo'

  utter_kuh:
  - text: |
      What is your email address?
  utter_subscribed:
  - text: |
      Check your inbox at {email} in order to finish subscribing to the newsletter!
  - text: You're all set! Check your inbox at {email} to confirm your subscription.
  - text: You've been subscribed, the newsletter will be sent to {email} shotly.
  utter_i_am_a_bot:
  - text: |
      I am a bot powered by RASA
  utter_my_name:
  - text: |
      I am KAI The Chatbot
  utter_my_age:
  - text: |
      I was made on June 2 2021 and I'm still being developed on a regular basis.

  utter_learn:
  - text: |
      A chatbot is a software application used to conduct an on-line chat conversation via text or text-to-speech, in lieu of providing direct contact with a live human agent.
      Did that answer help your question or do need more information?
    buttons:
    - title: "No thank you"
      payload: '/learn less'
    - title: "I am intrested in learning more"
      payload: '/learn more'

  utter_description:
  - text: |
      What do you want your chatbot to do? In a few words describe the purpose of your chatbot:

  utter_description_reply:
  - text: |
      Ah yes, we can definitely help with that. May I book an appointment for you with one of my colleagues?

  utter_book_demo:
  - text: |
      Sure. I will ask one of our humans to reach out. May I know:

  utter_learn_more:
  - text: |
      A chatbot is a software application used to conduct an on-line chat conversation via text or text-to-speech, in lieu of providing direct contact with a live human agent.
      Did that answer help your question or do need more information?
    buttons:
    - title: "No thank you"
      payload: '/learn less'
    - title: "I am intrested in learning more"
      payload: '/learn more'

  utter_learn_less:
  - text: |
      Ok great.Well, I am one message away. Don’t be shy.
  
  utter_learn_more1:
  - text: |
      Sure, I am more than happy to book an appointment for you.

  utter_ask_date:
  - text: |
      May I know the best date that works for you?

  utter_ask_time:
  - text: |
      Great, and what time??

  utter_ask_firstname:
  - text: |
      May I know your first name?

  utter_ask_lastname:
  - text: |
      May I know your last name?

  utter_ask_email:
  - text: |
      May I know your email address?
      
  utter_ask_country:
  - text: |   
      Which country are you in?
    
  utter_done_requesting:
  - text: |   
      Awesome Mr.{slot_firstname} {slot_lastname}, one of my colleagues will contact you shortly on your email {slot_email} to book an appointment on {slot_date} at {slot_time}

actions:
- '...'
- utter_greet
- utter_kuh
- utter_subscribed
- utter_i_am_a_bot
- utter_my_name
- utter_my_age
- utter_learn
- utter_description
- utter_description_reply
- utter_book_demo
- utter_learn_more
- utter_learn_less
- utter_learn_more1
- utter_ask_date
- utter_ask_time
- utter_ask_firstname
- utter_ask_lastname
- utter_ask_email
- utter_ask_country
- utter_done_requesting


forms:
  informative_form:
    required_slots:
      slot_date:
      - type: from_text
      slot_time:
      - type: from_text
      slot_firstname:
      - type: from_text
      slot_lastname:
      - type: from_text
      slot_email:
      - type: from_text
      slot_country:
      - type: from_text



session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true
```

forms.yml:

```
 forms:
      informative_form:
        required_slots:
          slot_date:
          - type: from_text
          slot_time:
          - type: from_text
          slot_firstname:
          - type: from_text
          slot_lastname:
          - type: from_text
          slot_email:
          - type: from_text
          slot_country:
          - type: from_text
```

nlu.yml:

```
version: "2.0"

nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - Hi
    - Hey!
    - Hallo
    - Good day
    - Good morning
    - howdy

- intent: subscribe
  examples: |
    - I want to get the newsletter
    - Can you send me the newsletter?
    - Can you sign me up for the newsletter?
    - Can I  on your mailing list?

- intent: inform
  examples: |
    - My email is example@example.com
    - random@example.com
    - Please send it to anything@example.com
    - Email is something@example.com

- intent: bot_challenge
  examples: |
    - Are you a bot?
    - Am I talking to a human?
    - is this a chatbot?
    - is this a real person?
    - you're a bot, aren't you

- intent: name
  examples: |
    - What's your name?
    - What did they name you??
    - what are you called?
    - What should I call you ?


- intent: learn
  examples: |
    - Learn about chatbots

- intent: describe
  examples: |
    - What do you want your chatbot to do? In a few words describe the purpose of your chatbot:

- intent: describe more
  examples: |
    - I want my chatbot to
    - I want it to do something
    - I want it to be something
    - I want it 
    - To do something
    - want it to be something
    - do something

- intent: book demo
  examples: |
    - Book a demo to test drive us

- intent: learn less
  examples: |
    - No, thank you.

- intent: learn 
  examples: |
    - I am interested in learning more.

- intent: kai101
  examples: |
    - Ask me your questions.
    - Ask me about the form.

- intent: date
  examples: |
    - May 31 1999
    - 31/05/1999
    - July 16 1978
    - 16/07/1978
    - January 4 1974
    - 04/01/1974
    - September 10 2003
    - 10/09/2003

- intent: time
  examples: |
    - 3:00 PM
    - 8:00 AM
    - 16:00
    - 8 in the morning
    - 4 afternoon
    - 12 in the morning
    - 4 in the evening

- intent: firstname
  examples: |
    - Kareem
    - Yehya
    - Mariam
    - Johnny
    - Charbel
    - Nour
    - Hanin
    - Hussein
    - John

- intent: lastname
  examples: |
    - Aridi
    - Abou Dargham
    - Harfouch
    - Abou Dagher
    - Smith
    - Malaeb

- intent: email
  examples: |
    - My email is example@example.com
    - random@example.com
    - Please send it to anything@example.com
    - Email is something@example.com

- intent: country
  examples: |
    - Lebanon
    - USA
    - UAE
    - Palestine
    - Syria
    - Iraq
    - Kuwait
    - United States
    - United Arab Emirates
    - Kuwait
    - Bahrain
    - Saudi Arabia
    - germany
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few observations to kicktart finding the right answer:

- could you please offer more context behind the problem you're facing? What command were you trying, what was the error stacktrace? It would be helpful if you could run `rasa shell --debug` and post the full debug log in your question.
- if you specify the form in `domain.yml`, you don't need to have a separate `forms.yml` file as per the [docs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms#defining-a-form)
- if you specified `influence_conversation` property as `false`, you don't need to use `type: unfeaturized` particularly because this has been [deprecated](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/domain/#unfeaturized-slot). Perhaps these should all be `type: text`?
- how are you using the form in `stories` and `rules`? are you able to share the contents of these files too? The [formbot example](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/tree/main/examples/formbot) is a good guideline to follow.